# Websocket Connection Failure when connecting to bot with DLS client

Tags: botframework

When connecting to a local instance of the bot through a proxy and ngrok, I am able to receive responses using DLS client. However, when testing with the app service I receive no responses back and the following error:

```
"Error ConnectionFailure : Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1000. Error details: Exceeded maximum websocket connection idle duration(> 300000ms) SessionId: 2ee9810a2916418a93dc1e978c49566b"
```

I have tried to restart the app service, ensured I have checked the "Enable Streaming Endpoint" box and toggled "Web sockets" to On, and even tried creating the app service. Looking at the app service logs, The GET request to the appservice returns 404, the bot receives a request and invokes StartWebSocketAsync but gets a 400 error and completed the request with http 400. There are no other exceptions being thrown, and locally everything seems to be working fine.

Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thank you!